# Deduplication Savings differs a lot between same two volumes

Tags: windows-server-2012, disk-space-utilization, deduplication

I run this robocopy command to copy all data from the existing volume to my new volume which will replace the old one in the near future:

`robocopy I:\ E:\ /E /COPYALL /PURGE /MIR /B /R:1 /W:1 /XD "Recycler" "Recycled" "$Recycle.bin" "System Volume Information" /XF "pagefile.sys" "swapfile.sys" "hiberfil.sys" /LOG:C:\Temp\copylog\logfile.log /NFL /NDL /NP`

I have Dedup active on Windows 2012 Server, MS says:

> Optimally, Data Deduplication should have 1 GB of memory for every 1
>   TB of logical data. For instance, if you are optimizing a 10 TB
>   volume, you would optimally need 10 GB of memory allocated for Data
>   Deduplication (1 GB * 10). This ratio will ensure the maximum
>   performance for Data Deduplication jobs.

I have:

Old Value which needs an ckdsk and will be replaced:

`Capacity 14.1 TB, Deduplication Savings 8.2 TB (34%)`

I might think that the chkdsk is needed because of chunkstore problems, which would explain why it saves me 34%, even if MS says it should not save that much space.

New Volume:

`Capacity 16.7 TB, Deduplication Savings 0.8 TB (4%)`

And there is still missing 3 TB data which I could not copy because of missing disk space.

I read that there is no possibility to increase the deduplication rate.

How can I save some disk space on my new volume? What is safe and what not? The volume is later a part of a HA-Filecluster of MS 2012 (no R2).

Comment: Dedup is per volume, when you copy all the data is copied, the dedup index is not used. You should maybe do storage space replica ? which is a sector by sector replica

Comment: Have you used `Get-DedupVolume` to make sure that the dedup settings are the same on both volumes?

Comment: Maybe you have to start a dedup run (`Start-DedupJob -Volume "<drive>" -Type Optimization`) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/deduplication/start-dedupjob?view=win10-ps

Comment: I already had run multiple dedup-job, they finished correctly:
`Start-DedupJob -Type Optimization -Volume E: -Memory 90 -Cores 90 -Priority High`

`Start-DedupJob -Type GarbageCollection -Volume E: -Memory 90 -Cores 90 -Priority High`

Get-DedupVolume shows me nothings else what I can see in the Server Manager FS Overview

Comment: Yes, but have you compared the output of `Get-DedupVolume` between the two volumes? And did you check the modify dates of the files like I suggested in your other question?

Comment: Modified Date is correct.